# Image of a strip

Tags: complex-analysis

> What is the image of the strip $0<\text{Imz}<1$ under the mapping $w=\frac{z-i}{z}$?

What I first did was find the poles, which is at the point $z=0$ which lies within the given strip $0<\text{Imz}<1$, thus I can conclude that -- at this point -- it will be sent to infinity. Now, if I take the point $z=1$, I get that it maps to $1-i$, but the answer given is: $$\{w:\text{Rew}<1\}-  \{w:|w-\frac12|\le \frac12\}$$
which I have no idea how they got?

Comment: Strictly speaking, $z=0$ does not lie within $0< \text{Im}(z)<1$, but rather, lies just outside of it, on the edge.

Comment: How much do you know about [Möbius transformations or linear fractional transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)?

Comment: @Landscape Good question. I have been studying that for about $4$ hours now.

Comment: @GlenO Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Then I think you can solve the problem by yourself once you get familiar with geometrical properties of linear fractional transformations.

Comment: @Landscape If I did I wouldn't be asking this question on here.

Comment: @Landscape Its 5 a.m. where I live and I have a final on this in about 5 hours and this question is my last question that I need to know in order to do good on the test. If you don't mind, can you explain it to me please?

Comment: Can I assume that all the basic properties about linear fractional transformations are allowed to use without proof or reference? If not, I am afraid I have no idea how to help you.

Comment: @Landscape actually nvm, someone answered this, thanks anyways!

Comment: Dimitris Dallas' answer looks fine to me. Maybe the only thing need further explanation is how to determine the image of the line $L:\mathrm{Im z}=1$. Denote your map by $f$. Since $f(L)$ does not contain $\infty$, it must be a circle. Let $f(p)$ be the center of the circle $f(L)$ and $f(q)=\infty$. Then $q=0$.  Since $f(p)$ and $f(q)$ are symmetric about the $f(L)$, $p$ and $q$ must be symmetric about $L$, i.e. $p=2i$. Then you find the center of the circle is $1/2$. Now pick any point $r$ in $L$, say $i$, the distance between $f(r)$ and $1/2$ gives you the radius of the circle.

Comment: @Landscape That is great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Q.matin: You are welcome. Good luck in your test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $Im(z)=0$ should be mapped to a circle or a line. Since $0$ is a pole of  $g(z)=\dfrac{z-i}{z}$ we conclude that the image of $Im(z)=0$ is a line, which passes through the points $g(1)=\dfrac{1-i}{1}=1-i$ and $g(-1)=\dfrac{-1-i}{-1}=1+i$. This is the line $Re(z)=1$. For $Im(z)>0 $ try $z=i$ and you can see that $g(\{Im(z)>0\})=\{Re(z)<1\}$

Now find the image of $Im(z)=1$. It is the circle : $\{w\in \mathbb C: |w-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}\}$. Take a $z\in \{Im(z)<1\}$, say $z=1$ and $g(z)$ is outside the circle. Therefore $g(\{Im(z)<1\})=\{|w-\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{1}{2}\}$

As a result: $$g(\{0<Im(z)<1\})=\{Re(z)<1\}\cap\{|w-\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{1}{2}\}=$$
$$\{Re(z)<1\}\setminus\{|w-\frac{1}{2}|\leq\frac{1}{2}\}$$

Comment: Thanks! How did you know that it is a circle of $$\{w\in \mathbb C: |w-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}\}?$$

Comment: $z\in \{Im(z)=1\}\Rightarrow z=x+i\Rightarrow g(z)=\dfrac{x+i-i}{x+i}\Rightarrow g(z)=\dfrac{x(x-i)}{x^2+1}\Rightarrow g(z)=\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}-\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}i=a+bi$. 

Now, $a^2+b^2=\dfrac{x^4}{(x^2+1)^2}+\dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}=\dfrac{x^4+2x^2+1}{(x^2+1)^2}-\dfrac{x^2+1}{(x^2+1)^2}=1-\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}=\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}=a$

Therefore, $a^2-a+b^2=0\Rightarrow (a-\dfrac{1}{2})^2+b^2=\dfrac{1}{4}$

Comment: Generally, it is easy to find that the image of a circle/line is a circle/line, but in the case of the circle you have to do some work in order to find which circle it is.